# How to call jQuery code from AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to call some jQuery code from AngularJS but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it cleanly. Here is an extract of my AngularJS code:

```
// Controller code
angular.module('application', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
        // Calling this will start refreshing/loading data
        var getData = function() {
            // Limit to 100 users
            var apiUrl = "http://apilink.com"; //api link goes here
            $http.get(apiUrl)
                .success(function(data) {
                    var users = [];

                    angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
                            var user = {
                                // User info stored here...
                            };

                            // Save the user to our list
                            users.push(user);
                    });

                    $scope.users = users;
                    $scope.usersExist = (users.length > 0);

                    // I THINK THE SCROLL CODE NEEDS TO BE HERE BECAUSE $scope.users SHOULD BE BOUND TO THE VIEW NOW?
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };
        ...
```

I later bind the function like this: `$scope.getData = getData;`

I have the following jQuery code, to automatically start scrolling the page down:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var intervalTime = 30000;

function initialise() {
    // Scroll to top
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 800);

    // And start scrolling to the bottom. Make it take 75% of the time to scroll to the bottom
    // so it doesn't hit the bottom and automatically re-load
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $('html, body').get(0).scrollHeight
    }, {
        duration: (0.75 * intervalTime)
    });

    $("html, body").bind("mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function() {
        $('html, body').stop();
        console.log("Stopping due to event");
    });

    // Re-load data
    angular.element('#MyController').scope().getData();
}
...
```

However, I've found that it's not scrolling the whole way. And I believe this is because the data from the `$http.get` hasn't been fully downloaded / bound at the time the jQuery code executes.

So what I want to do is call that jQuery function `initialise()` from the AngularJS controller in the spot where I have the comment in the code.

I have Google directives and services, but I can't really figure out how it works with regard to calling a jQuery function.

Comment: try putting the function outside of doc ready.

Comment: You don't need JQuery AT ALL when you are using AngularJS, in your case, you could use the `ngAnimate`, check the documentation.

Comment: I have seen AngularJS examples of things triggering when you scroll to a certain point in the page, but I want to automatically have the page scroll down to the bottom over say 60 seconds. Is that possible with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your  'initialise()' function into the controller and attach it to the scope:

```
$scope.initialise = function() {..etc
```

Then you can call the initialise function where you want

$scope.initialise();

However I recommend that you see how to scroll the page using angular functions - see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Also you don't need to load the function with 'ready' call anymore.